# A Lebesgue measurable set which is not Borel measurable (Lusin)

Tags: measure-theory

I am told that by means of continued fractions, Lusin or somebody else, has constructed examples of Lebesgue measurable sets which are not Borel measurable. Please, if you know a reference help me.

Comment: MathOverflow is for research-level questions only, see the FAQ: http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot. Here is a thread on Math Stack Exchange where this topic is addressed: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141017/264

Comment: @jorge: Google search gives lot of good results. Here is one which I liked: http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/non-lebesgue-measurable-sets/


Comment: @Chandra: But that is not what he is asking for...

Answer (score 1):

See this [this post](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/measure) from long ago